# accessExternalDTD property ignoring catalog file

Tags: maven, xmlcatalog

When running mvn clean install I get the following error that the external files can't be reached.

```
schema_reference: Failed to read schema document 'xml.xsd', because 'http' access is not allowed due to restriction set by the accessExternalSchema property.
```

This behaviour is as intended as I want my resources to be local. But shouldn't the catalog change avoid this error? Or is there something wrong with my config?

Parts of the pom file:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>xjc</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>xjc</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <catalog>${project.basedir}/catalog.xml</catalog>
        <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/</schemaDirectory>
        <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
        <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>set-additional-system-properties</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>set-system-properties</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <properties>
            <property>
                <name>javax.xml.accessExternalSchema</name>
                <value>file</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>javax.xml.accessExternalDTD</name>
                <value>file</value>
            </property>
        </properties>
        <outputFile/>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Catalog file:

```
<!DOCTYPE catalog 
    PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD Entity Resolution XML Catalog V1.0//EN" "http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/entity/release/1.0/catalog.dtd">
<catalog xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:entity:xmlns:xml:catalog">
    <rewriteSystem systemIdStartString="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" rewritePrefix="www.w3.org"/>
</catalog>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a whole lot of experimenting I found out that mye catalog was wrong. The use of

```
<property>
    <name>javax.xml.accessExternalSchema</name>
    <value>file</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>javax.xml.accessExternalDTD</name>
    <value>file</value>
</property>
```

was dropped and I changed my catalog to catalog.cat file, form catalog.xml, to this:

```
REWRITE_SYSTEM "http://www.w3.org" "www.w3.org"
REWRITE_SYSTEM "http://docs.oasis-open.org" "docs.oasis-open.org"
REWRITE_URI "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn"  "docs.oasis-open.org/wsn"
REWRITE_URI "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsrf"  "docs.oasis-open.org/wsrf"
```

The properties mentioned above does work with this catalog, but I droped it since with a working catalog, maven does not fetch any external schemas as long as the path in the catalog is correct. Making the properties obsolete.

Comment: Having the properties did help tough, as maven threw an error when the system tried no access external schemas and that was hard to catch by just reading the stacktrace

Answer (score 1):

i had a similar error and i try too many solutions that i found but the only one that works for me was:

Adding this to your pom in plugins tag

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <javax.xml.accessExternalSchema>all</javax.xml.accessExternalSchema>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Sorry for my bad english, i hope that this will work for you

Comment: Not what I was looking for, my problem is i want to force maven intousing local files instead of extarnal ones, and I have now succeded in this, thought trough other means. Your suggestion does however solve the error message! :)